# GeometryUtils.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined at Object../node_modules/three/examples/js/utils/GeometryUtils.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to replicate the following codepen:

```
                  https://codepen.io/jhealey5/pen/VxEZKK

                  loader.load(typeface, (font) => {
                       Array.from(triggers).forEach((trigger, idx) => {

                       texts[idx] = {};

                       texts[idx].geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry(trigger.textContent, {
                           font: font,
                           size: window.innerWidth * 0.02,
                           height: 4,
                           curveSegments: 10,
                       });

                       THREE.GeometryUtils.center(texts[idx].geometry)


                       texts[idx].particles = new THREE.Geometry();

                       texts[idx].points = 
                       THREE.GeometryUtils.randomPointsInGeometry(texts[idx].geometry, 
                       particleCount);

                       createVertices(texts[idx].particles, texts[idx].points)

                       enableTrigger(trigger, idx);

                     });
                     });
```

and the GeometryUtils.js file present in the three/examples/js/utils/ directory, but I get this error:

```
                      GeometryUtils.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined
                      at Object../node_modules/three/examples/js/utils/GeometryUtils.js
```

what is exactly going on here?

Comment: What version of `three.js` are you using? Most functions of `GeometryUtils` were removed with `R112` and the respective logic replaced with `MeshSurfaceSampler`, see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/18039.

Comment: "three": "^0.113.2",

Comment: Okay, that means functions like `GeometryUtils.center()` or `GeometryUtils.randomPointsInGeometry()` are not available anymore.

Comment: aren't there any alternatives?

Comment: You can restore the code from an older release. Or you use `MeshSurfaceSampler`.